# Example Jar in Hadoop release

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop with book 'Hadoop in Action' by Chuck Lam. In first chapter the books says that Hadoop installation will have example jar and by running 'hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar' will show all the examples. But when I run the command then it throw error 'Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar'. My guess is that installed Hadoop doesn't have example jar. I have installed 'hadoop-2.1.0-beta.tar.gz' on cygwin on Win 7 laptop. Please suggest how to get example jar.

Comment: The examples jar is not found actually !

Answer (score 2):

run following command

hadoop jar PathToYourJarFile wordcount inputPath OutputPath

you can get examples jar file at your hadoop installation directory

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest here is you should manually go to the Hadoop installation directory and look for a jar name similar to hadoop-examples.jar yourself. Different distribution can have different names for the jar.

If you are in Cygwin, while in the Hadoop Installation directory you can also do a `ls *examples*.jar` to find the same, narrowing down the file listing to any jar file containing *examples* as a string.

You can then directly use the jar file name like --

```
hadoop jar <exampleJarYourFound.jar>
```

Hope this takes you to a solution.